# error: list<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'map<string, dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies

this is my api handling section

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import '../Utils/ConstantsPages/toast_page.dart';

class ApiManager {
  Dio _dio = Dio();
  static const String BaseUrl = "-------";

  outletCityListApi() async {
    print("outletCityListApi");
    try {
      Response<Object> response = await _dio.get(
        BaseUrl + "Api/Outlet/CityList",
        options: Options(
          headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': "application/json",
            'Accept': "application/json",
          },
        ),
      );
      return response.data;
    } on Exception catch (error) {
      print("error7 $error");
      return Future.error('Unexpected error  $error');
    }
  }
}
```

This is my bloc section, in this section i am getting error,

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import '../../../ApiManager/api_manager.dart';
import '../../../Models/outlet_city_list_model.dart';
import 'outlet_city_state.dart';

class OutletCityCubit extends Cubit<OutletCityState> {
  ApiManager _apiManager = ApiManager();

  OutletCityCubit() : super(OutletCityInitialState()) {}

  outletCityList() async {
    List<OutletCityListModel> outletCityListData =[];

    emit(OutletCityLoadingState());
    // here   await _apiManager.outletCityListApi().then((val) {
      log("outletCityList:: $val");
      emit(OutletCityLoadingOffState());
      if (val["StatusCode"] == 200) {
        log("data::::: ${val["ResponsePacket"]}");
        outletCityListData.add(OutletCityListModel.fromJson(val["ResponsePacket"])); // and here
        emit(OutletCityCodeSentState(outletCityListData as OutletCityListModel));
      } else if (val["StatusCode"] == 400) {
        emit(OutletCityErrorState(val["Message"]));
      }
    });
  }
}
```

this is my model

```
class OutletCityListModel {
  int? id;
  String? city;
  List<OutletList>? outletList;

  OutletCityListModel({this.id, this.city, this.outletList});

  OutletCityListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    city = json['City'];
    if (json['OutletList'] != null) {
      outletList = <OutletList>[];
      json['OutletList'].forEach((v) {
        outletList!.add(new OutletList.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Id'] = this.id;
    data['City'] = this.city;
    if (this.outletList != null) {
      data['OutletList'] = this.outletList!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class OutletList {
  int? id;
  String? title;
  String? address;
  String? city;
  int? cityId;
  bool? isTakeAway;
  bool? isDelivery;
  bool? isCodAvailable;

  OutletList(
      {this.id,
        this.title,
        this.address,
        this.city,
        this.cityId,
        this.isTakeAway,
        this.isDelivery,
        this.isCodAvailable});

  OutletList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['Id'];
    title = json['Title'];
    address = json['Address'];
    city = json['City'];
    cityId = json['CityId'];
    isTakeAway = json['IsTakeAway'];
    isDelivery = json['IsDelivery'];
    isCodAvailable = json['IsCodAvailable'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Id'] = this.id;
    data['Title'] = this.title;
    data['Address'] = this.address;
    data['City'] = this.city;
    data['CityId'] = this.cityId;
    data['IsTakeAway'] = this.isTakeAway;
    data['IsDelivery'] = this.isDelivery;
    data['IsCodAvailable'] = this.isCodAvailable;
    return data;
  }
}
```

this type of my data

```
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Message": null,
  "ResponsePacket": [
    {
      "Id": 100,
      "City": "Jaipur",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 106,
          "Title": "Jagatpura",
          "Address": "RV34+FXQ, Karolan Ka Barh, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302017, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 108,
          "Title": "Mansarover",
          "Address": "102, First Floor, Okay Plus Square, Madhyam Marg, Mansarovar Sector 7, Agarwal Farm, Sector 9, Mansarovar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302020, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 109,
          "Title": "Vidhyadhar Nagar",
          "Address": "A-15, Sector 2, Central Spine, Vidyadhar Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302023, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 110,
          "Title": "Elements Mall",
          "Address": "8th, Ajmer Rd, DCM, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302021, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 111,
          "Title": "Raja Park",
          "Address": "281, Bholasar, Gurunanakpura, Raja Park, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302004, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 112,
          "Title": "Tonk Road",
          "Address": "2, 2, Tonk Rd, Vasundhara Colony, Gandhi Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302015, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 114,
          "Title": "Khatipura",
          "Address": "A-7, Khatipura Rd, Hanuman Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302021, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 124,
          "Title": "C-Scheme",
          "Address": "E-2, E-2, Gokhle Marg, Panch Batti, C Scheme, Ashok Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302001, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 125,
          "Title": "Jhotwara",
          "Address": "Shop No, 83, Kalwar Rd, Harnathapura, Jhotwara, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302012, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 128,
          "Title": "Pratap Nagar",
          "Address": "The Needles, shop no-Lg 44, besment The rise building, Haldighati Marg, below relince degital, Sanganer, Sector 6, Pratap Nagar, Jaipur, Rajasthan 302033, India",
          "City": "Jaipur",
          "CityId": 100,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 101,
      "City": "Kota",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 113,
          "Title": "Tripolis Mall, Rajeev Gandhi Nagar",
          "Address": "showroom no. 7 , Patanjali mega store , Tripolis, plot 2A, Jhalawar Road, Instrumentation Limited Colony, Kota, Rajasthan 324005, India",
          "City": "Kota",
          "CityId": 101,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 115,
          "Title": "Kunhari, Landmark City",
          "Address": "Ghalot heights boys hostel, 4, Laxman Vihar, Kunadi, Electricity Board Area, Kota, Rajasthan 324008, India",
          "City": "Kota",
          "CityId": 101,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 127,
          "Title": "Borkheda Coral Park - Kota",
          "Address": "Coral Park Road No. 1, Rajasthan 325201, India",
          "City": "Kota",
          "CityId": 101,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 131,
          "Title": "Jawahar Nagar",
          "Address": "5R3Q+FR6, New Jawahar Nagar, Talwandi, Kota, Rajasthan 324005, India",
          "City": "Kota",
          "CityId": 101,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 132,
          "Title": "Station Road",
          "Address": "23, shitla mandir chowk, nr. Amar dhaba, Bhimganj Mandi, Kota, Rajasthan 324002, India",
          "City": "Kota",
          "CityId": 101,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 103,
      "City": "Gurugram",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 117,
          "Title": "Sapphire 83, Gurugram",
          "Address": "83, Vatika Rd, Sector 83, Gurugram, Haryana 122001, India",
          "City": "Gurugram",
          "CityId": 103,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 119,
          "Title": "Cyber Hub U block,Gurugram",
          "Address": "75/52, Block U, DLF Phase 3, Sector 24, Gurugram, Haryana 122002, India",
          "City": "Gurugram",
          "CityId": 103,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 105,
      "City": "Delhi",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 120,
          "Title": "Laxmi Nagar",
          "Address": "Laxmi Nagar, Veer Savarkar Block, Block H, Sector 18, Kavi Nagar, Ghaziabad, Uttar Pradesh 110092, India",
          "City": "Delhi",
          "CityId": 105,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 121,
          "Title": "Dwarka",
          "Address": "9A, Uttam Nagar, Block C, Mansa Ram Park, Hastsal, Delhi, 110059, India",
          "City": "Delhi",
          "CityId": 105,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 106,
      "City": "Jodhpur",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 126,
          "Title": "Sardarpura Jodhpur",
          "Address": "583, 583, 9th C Rd, Patrakar Colony, Sardarpura, Jodhpur, Rajasthan 342003, India",
          "City": "Jodhpur",
          "CityId": 106,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 107,
      "City": "Udaipur",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 129,
          "Title": "R K Circle",
          "Address": "Plot no. 1 - 2, gaurav path, RK Circle, near bharat petrol pump, Pulla, Pulla Bhuwana, Mahaveer Colony Park, Udaipur, Rajasthan 313001, India",
          "City": "Udaipur",
          "CityId": 107,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 130,
          "Title": "Chetak Mall",
          "Address": "HMRR+GHQ, Post Office Rd, Chetak Circle, Madhuban, Udaipur, Rajasthan 313001, India",
          "City": "Udaipur",
          "CityId": 107,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 108,
      "City": "Ajmer",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 133,
          "Title": "Cinemall-Ajmer",
          "Address": "Cine Mall, FJJJ+9GC, Gaurav Path, Apna Nagar, Vaishali Nagar, Ajmer, Rajasthan 305004, India",
          "City": "Ajmer",
          "CityId": 108,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 109,
      "City": "Lucknow",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 134,
          "Title": "Vikas Nagar Lucknow",
          "Address": "C-2/67 EKTA BAZAAR VIKAS NAGAR KURSI ROAD, Kursi Rd, Sector 2, Vikas Nagar, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226022, India",
          "City": "Lucknow",
          "CityId": 109,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 135,
          "Title": "Ashiana Lucknow",
          "Address": "77, Sector B, Bargawan, Ashiyana, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226012, India",
          "City": "Lucknow",
          "CityId": 109,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 136,
          "Title": "Vrindavan Yojana Lucknow",
          "Address": "QX68+WF2, Vrindavan Colony, Baraulikhalilabad, Uttar Pradesh 226029, India",
          "City": "Lucknow",
          "CityId": 109,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 138,
          "Title": "Gomtinagar",
          "Address": "6, Shaheed Path, Virat Khand, Gomti Nagar, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226010, India",
          "City": "Lucknow",
          "CityId": 109,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        },
        {
          "Id": 139,
          "Title": "Rajajipuram",
          "Address": "Amar Plaza, 13/105, near Trendy Store, New Haiderganj, Rajajipuram, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226017, India",
          "City": "Lucknow",
          "CityId": 109,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 110,
      "City": "Chomu",
      "OutletList": [
        {
          "Id": 137,
          "Title": "Chomu",
          "Address": "5P85+6WP, Krishna Vihar, Chomu, Rajasthan 303702, India",
          "City": "Chomu",
          "CityId": 110,
          "IsTakeAway": true,
          "IsDelivery": true,
          "IsCodAvailable": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Success": true,
  "Errors": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
outletCityListData.add(OutletCityListModel.fromJson(val["ResponsePacket"]));
```

The methods fromJson expect to receive a `Map<String, dynamic>`, but you're passing a list.
You're trying to map the OutletList with a list of ResponsePacket. OutletList is a list inside each element of another list.
You should implement a ResponsePacket class to map each responsePacket. And map a Outlet inside each element of the OutletList.

```
class ResponsePacket {
   ...
   final List<Outlet> outletList;
   ...
}

final List<ResponsePacket> responsePacketList = 
List.from(val['ResponsePacket']).map((e) => `ResponsePacket.fromMap(e)).toList();`
```

and inside the `ResponsePacket.fromMap` the outlet mapper

```
outletList: List.from(map['OutletList']).map((e) => Outlet.fromMap(e)).toList(),
```